# CakePHP performance issue

Tags: apache, cakephp

I am load testing my CakePHP project using `Apache work bench`.

I experience that if I put exit; at the end of the `app/views/layouts/default.ctp` the performance increase 6 times. It still renders the page completely.

I wonder what so complex runs after rendering the complete view that making the page very slow.

Thanks

Comment: No there are no errors. I verified.